# $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n-1)^{n}(x+1)^n}{2^{n-1}n^n}$ converegence domain

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

> **Exercise**:Find the convergence domain of the series $$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n-1)^{n}(x+1)^n}{2^{n-1}n^n}$$

I tried to solve it in the following way:

Applying the comparison test:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n-1)^{n}(x+1)^n}{2^{n-1}n^n}\leqslant\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n-1)^{n}(x+1)^n}{n^n}$$

Now applying the root test:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n-1)^{}(x+1)}{n}=2(x+1)$$

$$2x+1<1\implies x<-\frac{1}{2}$$

*Solution(Book)*:$-2<x<0$

**Question**:

What am I doing wrong? What should I do?

Comment: The comparison test might might not tell you _everywhere_ the original series converges. In addition, you didn't take into account the sign of $x$, which may be affect the inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the ratio test directly:$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{(2n-1)^n|x+1|^n)}{2^{n-1}n^n}}=\sqrt[n]2\frac{(2n-1)|x+1|}{2n}\to|x+1|.$$Therefore, the series converges if $|x+1|<1$ and it diverges if $|x+1|>1$.

If $|x+1|=1$, then$$\left|\frac{(2n-1)^n|x+1|^n)}{2^{n-1}n^n}\right|=2\left(1-\frac1{2n}\right)^n\to\frac2{\sqrt e}\neq0.$$Therefore the series diverges if $|x+1|=1$. So, the domain of convergence is indeed $(-2,0)$.

Comment: Could please tell me what was I doing wrong?

Comment: @PedroGomes Applying the comparaison test, you were destroyong information. It's as if I said: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{2^n}<\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n$ and therefore the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{2^n}$ converges if $0<x<1$. Yes, it does. But it also converges if $1\leqslant x<2$.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is incorrectly applying the root test. You get
$$
L = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n^{1/n}
 = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(2n-1)(x+1)}{2n} \frac{1}{2^{1/n}} = x+1,
$$
and you must force $|L|<1$ which yields $|x+1|<1$ with solution $-2<x<0$.